# CSS z-index not working properly

Tags: css, z-index

say I have the following:

```
<div id="fader"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Blah Blah</div>
    <div class="content">Blah Blah</div>
    <div class="content">
         <div id="form">form goes here</div>
</div>
<div id="form2">Form goes here</div>
```

Now #form is actually invisible until a button is clicked. At that point, I want fader to black out the entire page, and the #form shows up.

I have this working by using `position: absolute` and the correct `z-index`. Now, #wrapper is set to a z-index lower than #fader's z-index. I want #form z-index to be higher than #fader, but still be inside #wrapper! Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi there.  We don't have enough info to work with... any way you could create a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Wow. Too many words, not enough code. Make a fiddle!

Answer (score 2):

Z-index only applies to positioned elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/sSKZS/1/

```
#wrapper {z-index: 1; position: relative;}
#fader {z-index: 2; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#form2 {z-index: 3; position: absolute;}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, because #form is set within the context of #wrapper.

If you think of #fader, #wrapper, and #form2 as busses speeding down the highway, they can all pass one another, merge lanes, etc. The passengers in the #wrapper vehicle — the .content divs and #form — move with #wrapper and can move about inside the “bus”, but they’re confined within it. (Depending on your CSS, #form may be nested in *another* context of .content, but that's a little out of scope.)

You’d have to move #form out of #wrapper into the body, either dynamically with a JavaScript event or on page load. But either way, it can’t be on the bus.